# Clip an image with PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

In PDFBOX, I need to render a polygon with a background image or clip an image with my polygon, as in the screenshot example.

I'm trying to understand how PDContentStream.clip() or PDContentStream.shadingfill() works but this is not clear for me.

example : image clipped with polygon in JavaFX

[image: exemple : image clipped with polygon in JavaFX]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `PDContentStream.shadingfill()` for this task.

All you need is to

- define the clip path
- clip (and stroke to draw a line along the clip area like in your example)
- draw the image.

There is just one complication: The implementer of the PDFBox `PDContentStream.clip()` method apparently considered the option to both clip and stroke (or fill) a path unnecessary and after clipping immediately dropped the path definition:

```java
public void clip() throws IOException
{
    if (inTextMode)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error: clip is not allowed within a text block.");
    }
    writeOperator("W");

    // end path without filling or stroking
    writeOperator("n");
}
```

Thus, if you indeed want to clip and stroke using the same path definition, you need to bypass the PDFBox `clip` method.

So, you can proceed like this

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDImageXObject pdImage = ...;

int w = pdImage.getWidth();
int h = pdImage.getHeight();

PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

contentStream.setStrokingColor(25, 200, 25);
contentStream.setLineWidth(4);
contentStream.moveTo(cropBox.getLowerLeftX(), cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + h/2);
contentStream.lineTo(cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + w/3, cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + 2*h/3);
contentStream.lineTo(cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + w, cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + h/2);
contentStream.lineTo(cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + w/3, cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + h/3);
contentStream.closePath();
//contentStream.clip();
contentStream.appendRawCommands("W ");
contentStream.stroke();

contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, cropBox.getLowerLeftX(), cropBox.getLowerLeftY(), w, h);

contentStream.close();

doc.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "image-clipped.pdf"));
doc.close();
```

*([AddImage](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/AddImage.java#L116) test `testImageAddClipped`)*

which with my example image results in

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Very clear, your solved my problem perfectly, thank you very much !
Now, I can clip my first image but when i add a second image, it's also clipped with previous polygon. There is a "unclip" function for disable clipping ? May be I need to configure a new rectangle clip on entire page ?

Comment: I find solution, just saveGraphicsState() before clipping and restoreGraphicState() after.

Comment: Correct, enveloping instructions like it is done in PDFBox with `saveGraphicsState()` and `restoreGraphicState()` is very common in PDFs to reset the graphics state to a previous state.